# call python script with custom sys.path

Tags: python

Sometimes I need to add custom paths to my python scripts to find certain modules, with `sys.path.append("/some/directory/")` at the beginning. However, I have a bunch of files that need to use this custom path and I'd like to avoid writing this in every file. I have a main python script that automatically runs all these files using `subprocess.call("python", "my_script.py")`. How could I achieve the equivalent of `sys.path.append("/some/directory/")` on every file, from the main script?

Comment: Just write a simple helper function that does it for you?

Comment: Use the environment variable PYTHONPATH

Comment: It's time to write a `setup.py` for all that stuff in `/some/directory/` and install it properly.  Start here:  https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: Are you on windows or Linux/Mac?

Comment: The real question is why you are calling Python scripts from a subprocess instead of just importing them directly.

Comment: These scripts are unit tests scripts for a small library, located inside a `test` subdirectory of the entire project and I'm constantly changing the source code of the library, so the modules I want to import are not really from a regular library. Maybe there's a better way to deal with unit testing, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I just found out that writing a `setup.py` file makes much more sense. I wasn't aware of all this python packaging stuff. Running `python setup.py develop` seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the directory to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` before invoking `subprocess.call()` you can achieve the same result as adding the directory via `sys.path.append()` for a local call.  Something like:

```
import os
p = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', script_directory_to_add).split(os.pathsep)
if script_directory_to_add not in p:
    p.append(script_directory_to_add)
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.pathsep.join(p)
```

Comment: `a = ...abspath...; p = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', ''); if a not in p: if p: p += os.pathsep; <unindent> os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = p + a` would handle an existing but empty path correctly and not duplicate paths.